# Google Calendar API: A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have created a calendar list on the Google Calendar API. I have a job scheduler running on a server which it will add new events to the calendar list using Service Account. It was working fine previously, but recently I keep on receiving HTTP Code 500 Backend Error when adding a new event.

Tried exponential backoff solution and Google APIs Explorer, none of them works.

Here's the request and response from the APIs Explorer,

```
Request

POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{MY_CALENDAR_LIST_ID}%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2016-07-29T14:00:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2016-07-29T12:00:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London"
 },
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": true
 },
 "summary": "Some Title of the Event",
 "description": "Some Description for the Event",
 "location": "London"
}



Response


null

{
 "error": {
  "code": -1,
  "message": "A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed."
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you try slowing it down a little.   That error is normally flood protection.

Comment: Does that mean Google is throttling my requests? My web app does not generate that much of traffic with merely 1000 requests/day.

Comment: Yes that could be the problem you can send a max of 10 requests a second.   The best solution for this error is ad a pause and try the same request again it will normally work.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but it doesnt work as well. I only send 1 request every 60 secs now. However, sometimes I notice the event has been inserted into my calendar list, but I did not receive any successful response from the Google Calendar API.